# Laravel 5.4: Unable to show crud contents in views

Tags: php, html, laravel, view, laravel-5.4

I have here a simple blog web app. The trouble is when I wanna output blog categories in the databases. I successfully save in in the db and showed it when I tested it when I used return statement. But when I tried to put the output on views categories would not show on the view pages. It only shows blank bullet when I used

in my blade view. Also when I add something on the database on categories and refresh the page another bullet would be added on my view.

Also the blog application has a homepage where a preview is shown to be able to show the full blog entry you must click view on the blog entry listed on the homepage.

the blade where something not right is happening

```
\posts\view.blade.php
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Post View</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <ul>
                            @if(count($categories) > 0)
                                @foreach($categories->all() as $category)
                                    <li>
                                        <a href='{{url("category/{$category->id}")}}'>
                                        {{ $category->$category  }}</a>
                                    </li>
                                @endforeach
                            @else
                                <p>No category found!</p>
                            @endif
                        </ul>
                        <ul> adsfafs</ul>




                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">


                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

the route
    //web.php
    Auth::routes();

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('/post', 'PostController@post');
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfileController@profile');
Route::get('/category', 'CategoryController@category');
Route::post('/addCategory', 'CategoryController@addCategory');
Route::post('/addProfile', 'ProfileController@addProfile');
Route::post('/addPost', 'PostController@addPost');

Route::get('/view/{id}', 'PostController@view');
```

the controller

```
//PostController.php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use App\Category;
use App\Post;
use Auth;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function post(){
        $categories = Category::all();
        $posts= Post::all();
        //return $posts;
        //exit(); pang testing

        return view('posts.post', ['categories'=> $categories, 'posts'=>$posts]);
    }

    public function addPost(Request $request){
        //return $request->input('post_title');
        $this->validate($request,[
            'post_title'=> 'required',
            'post_body'=> 'required',
            'category_id'=> 'required',
            'post_image'=> 'required',

        ]);
        //return "validation pss";
        $posts = new Post;
        $posts->post_title=$request->input('post_title');
        $posts->user_id= Auth::user()->id; //returns user details
        $posts->post_body=$request->input('post_body');
        $posts->category_id=$request->input('category_id');

        if(Input::hasFile('post_image')){
            $file = Input::file('post_image');
            $file -> move(public_path(). '/posts/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
            $url = URL::to("/") . '/posts/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();

        }
        $posts->post_image= $url;
        $posts->save();

        return redirect('/home')->with('response','Post Published Successfully');

    }

    public function view($post_id){
        $post = Post::where('id', '=', $post_id)->get();
        $categories = Category::all();

        return view('posts.view', ['post'=>$post, 'categories'=>$categories ]);

    }
    public function edit($post_id){
        return $post_id;

    }
}
```

the homepage

```
@extends('layouts.app')
<style type="text/css">
    .avatar{
        border-radius: 100%;
        max-width: 100px;
    }
</style>
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            @if(count($errors)>0)
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
                        @endforeach

            @endif

                    @if(session('response'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">{{  session('response')}}</div>

                    @endif
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        @if(!empty($profile))
                        <img src="{{ $profile->profile_pic }}" class="avatar" alt="">

                        @else
                        <img src="{{ url('images/avatar.jpg')}}" class="avatar" alt="">
                        @endif

                        @if(!empty($profile))
                        <p class="lead">{{ $profile->name }}</p>

                        @else
                        <p></p>
                        @endif

                        @if(!empty($profile))
                        <p class="lead">{{ $profile->designation }}</p>

                        @else
                        <p></p>
                        @endif



                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                        @if(count($posts) > 0)
                            @foreach($posts->all() as $post)
                                <h4>{{ $post -> post_title }} </h4>
                                <img src="{{ $post -> post_image }}" alt="">
                                <p>{{ substr($post->post_body, 0, 150) }}</p>

                                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                                    <li role="presentation">
                                        <a href="{{ url("/view/{$post->id}") }}">
                                            <span class="fa fa-eye">View</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="presentation">
                                        <a href="{{ url("/edit/{$post->id}") }}">
                                            <span class="fa fa-pencil-square">Edit</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li role="presentation">
                                        <a href="{{ url("/delete/{$post->id}") }}">
                                            <span class="fa fa-trash">Delete</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>

                                <cite style="float left;">Posted on: {{ date('M j, Y H:i', strtotime($post->updated_at)) }}</cite>
                            @endforeach

                        @else
                            <p>No Post Available!</p> 
                        @endif

                    </div>                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit this part:

```
 @foreach($categories->all() as $category)
   <li>
     <a href='{{url("category/{$category->id}")}}'>
        {{ $category->$category  }}</a>
   </li>
 @endforeach
```

Replace it with:

```
  @foreach($categories as $category)
   <li>
     <a href='{{url("category/{$category->id}")}}'>
        {{ $category  }}</a>
   </li>
 @endforeach
```

You had used `all()` in your controller to get the categories from your model. Just loop through the categories now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<li>
    <a href='{{url("category/{$category->id}")}}'>
    {{ $category->$category  }}</a>
</li>
```

I guess `$category->$category` should be `$category->category`, if property `category` is the name of the categories in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing "all()" in $categories->all() in post/view.blade.php